# Probability that new baby born is a boy in a nursery

Tags: probability

There are $2$ boys and unknown number of girls in a nursery. A new baby is just born inside the room. We pick randomly a baby from the room, it turns out that the baby is a boy. What is the probability that the new baby just born is a boy?

We can solve this using Bayes' rule, as follows, $P(\text{new baby is boy} | \text{picked a boy})$. We end up getting $\frac{3}{5}$. Why is this answer intuitively not dependent on the number of girls in the nursery?

Comment: For the answer, it is important to specify if you pick newborn babies with or without returning them after having determined their gender.

Comment: @NeitherNor what do you mean by returning the baby?

Comment: @Radial I mean, do you pick the random baby from the nursery with or without replacement, i.e. are you returning the baby afterwards or do you keep it?

Comment: @NeitherNor I don’t quite follow what you’re saying.  If you’re asking if we pick multiple times, then the answer is that we only pick once (As the problem does not state we get a second pick).

Comment: @NeitherNor If we only pick once then it doesn’t matter whether or not the baby stays in the nursery.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before the new baby is born, there are 2 boys (Andy and Bob).  The new baby (NB) is born, then we pick a baby at random and get a boy.  In order for this to happen, one of the following scenarios occurred:

1. NB is a boy and we picked Andy
2. NB is a boy and we picked Bob
3. NB is a boy and we picked NB
4. NB is a girl and we picked Andy
5. NB is a girl and we picked Bob

In three of these five cases, NB is a boy, so the probability is $\frac{3}{5}$

The number of girls at the start is irrelevant, because changing that number doesn't change the relative probability of any of scenarios $1-5$ occurring

Comment: "The number of girls at the start is irrelevant, because changing that number doesn't change the probability of any of scenarios 1−5 occuring" - probably better to say that it doesn't change that the scenarios are equally likely (which would probably also be good to point out explicitly). Adding more girls *does* lower the probability of scenarios 1 - 5, just not in a way that's meaningful to the result.

Comment: Yes.  That's what i meant

Answer (score 6):

Suppose there are initially $g$ girls in the room.  Let $A$ be the event that the new baby is a boy, $B$ the event that the baby picked is a boy.  I presume we are supposed to assume $\mathbb P(A) = 1/2$ (although in real life that is not quite true).  Then $\mathbb P(B\mid A) = 3/(g+3)$ and $\mathbb P(B\mid A^c) = 2/(g+3)$,
so $$\mathbb P(A\mid B) = \frac{\mathbb P(B\mid A) \mathbb P(A)}{\mathbb P(B\mid A) \mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B\mid A^c) \mathbb P(A^c)} = \frac{3}{5}$$
The point is that $g$ has the same effect on both $\mathbb P(B\mid A)$ and $\mathbb P(B\mid A^c)$, a multiplicative factor of  $1/(g+3)$ in both cases, which cancels out in $\mathbb P(A\mid B)$.

Comment: "in real life that is not quite true" $${}$$ The other thing that in real life is not quite true that is almost always assumed in exercises in elementary probability courses is that the sexes of babies born to a couple are independent of each other. Someone published something based on data from the 1970 census of the United States about this question and I seem to recall it left a lot of questions unanswered, and I wonder if anything further has been done.

Comment: The accepted answer makes no assumption on P(A)=0.5. So I assume it's possible using Bayes theory to also come to the same result?

Comment: The accepted answer does assume $\mathbb P(A)=1/2$ by taking the five cases to have equal probabilities.